# Zabbix 4.2 Character and Number

Tags: zabbix

I have recently set up a zabbix server and am now trying to get data via SNMP from a FreeNAS (FreeBSD) Server. When checking snmp with snmpwalk I get the correct results. So I proceeded and added the snmp-command in zabbix server.

The weird thing: When I set up the Zabbix Item as `Character` I get the correct Information from the Freenas. When I set it to `Number` I do not get any Information at all.

Can anybody help ? I am out of ideas.

Comment: In the "items" view of the host you should find a `!` mark on the right of the item, hover on it: what does it say?

Comment: it is working now. dont know why it didnt work.